# Sliced Line on column chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, linechart, column-chart

How Can I draw a graph like this(highlighted area) using highcharts?
[image: Line on each column]

Comment: Create another series, link it to the main series, disable event tracking and marker. http://jsfiddle.net/n5v4um82/

Comment: Thanks @morganfree, that worked like a charm

Comment: Can we achieve this with plotbands or plotlines?

Comment: You mean that plot lines will be split into parts just as the lines in the above picture. It cannot be done without [extending/modifying Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)